# Warp multiple elements in random levels

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I'm kinda stuck...
How can I wrap a collection of DOM elements on different levels in a combined div?

Here an example:

```
<div id="item1">
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="item3">
        <div id="item4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item5"></div>
</div>
```

e.g. Wrap #item2 and #item4 in #COMBO should look like this:

```
<div id="item1">
    <div id="COMBO">
        <div id="item2"></div>
        <div id="item3">
             <div id="item4"></div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div id="item5"></div>
</div>
```

or any other random selectors like #item1 and #item2 and #item4 should like this:

```
<div id="COMBO">
     <div id="item1">
        <div id="item2"></div>
        <div id="item3">
             <div id="item4"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item5"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

I would need to be able to select multiple elements like $("#item2, #item4") or $("#item1, #item2, #item4") and all items in between should be included in the wrapper.

---

@LeGEC

Selector:

```
$('#item2, #item5').myWrap();
```

Result:

```
<div id="item1">
    <div id="COMBO">
        <div id="item2"></div>
        <div id="item3">
             <div id="item4"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

This example should make it clear:

Selector:

```
$('#item4, #item5').myWrap();
```

Result:

```
<div id="item1">
    <div id="item2"></div>
    <div id="COMBO">
        <div id="item3">
             <div id="item4"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="item5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How would `$('#item2, #item5').myWrap()` look like ?

Comment: Please see my updated comment.

Answer (score 0):

use `wrap` and `wrapInner`

```
 $( "#item1" ).wrapInner( "<div id='COMBO'></div>" );//for firstscenario
```

**[First Scenario Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE7v7/)**

```
$( "#item1" ).wrap( "<div id='COMBO'></div>" );//for second scenarion
```

**[Second Scenario Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE7v7/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, but I probably wasn't clear enough. 
Please see my updated question.

Comment: in his first question #item5 is outside the combo

Comment: @Mayko:i interchanged the position while answering. Fixed it. should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://api.jquery.com/wrap/ for this.

For example:

```
$('#item1').wrap('<div id="COMBO"></div>');
```

and other ways.

Answer (score 0):

First question: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/MSdQ7/

So you can use wrapAll if you want to wrap the provided selectors in one element.

```
$('#item2, #item3').wrapAll('<div id="COMBO"></div>');
```

Second question: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/MSdQ7/1/

This will wrap #item1 and all its content in one element

```
$('#item1').wrap('<div id="COMBO"></div>')
```

To wrap each item in its own combo: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/MSdQ7/3/

This will wrap each item in its own element

```
$('#item2, #item3, #item4').wrap('<div id="COMBO"></div>')
```

Have a look at all of these: https://api.jquery.com/?s=wrap

Answer (score 0):

You will have to :

- look for the closest common ancestor,
- select the relevant children inside this ancestor,
- wrap those children inside the wrapper.